# ionic 2 app doesn't update after changing code

Tags: ionic2

I'm new to the Ionic framework, and I've been codeing a few days. Until yesterday, as I changed my code and saved it, the view in the web browser was updated (after I had run it with "ionic serve"). All as it shoud be.

Now the wiew in the browser is not updating. It's building only once, when I start it, then nothing happens. Even if I reload the page in the web browser, nothing changes, it's still the old content in the page.

It doesn't seem to have to do with my specific project: also if I create a new project with "ionic start test blank", and run "ionic serve", it doesn't get updated.

I tried to "npm uninstall -g ionic" and "npm uninstall -g cordova" and reinstall everything, but nothing changes.

Strange. Where should I start looking for the problem?

Comment: have you tried with the browser developer console opened? Have you tried to manually reload the page from your browser? What kind of browser are you using?

Comment: Anyway [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/363) you can find a discussion